# Sharing angular material module in whole project

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I had import all the angular material module in my app.module

```
@NgModule({imports: [
CdkTableModule,
MatAutocompleteModule,
MatButtonModule,
MatCardModule,
MatCheckboxModule,
MatIconModule,
MatInputModule,
MatProgressBarModule,
MatProgressSpinnerModule,
MatRadioModule,
MatRippleModule,
MatSelectModule,
MatSidenavModule,
MatSliderModule,
MatSlideToggleModule,
MatSnackBarModule],})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now my program will redirect to either login page or layout page. The code is shown at below:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {AuthGuard} from './shared/guard/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
   {path: '', loadChildren: './layout/layout.module#LayoutModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
   {path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'}];

@NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],
   exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

How can I use all the angular material from here instead of import all the material again in Login.module and Layout.module

I had done it with compoent: `LoginComponent` and I work but how can I do it in loadChildren?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Angular `NgModule`-s declarations are only applicable to the current components. Means if you have imported `MaterialModule` in the `AppModule`, only components that are added in the declarations of the `AppModule` can use elements from the `MaterialModule`. You can create a custom `MaterialModule`, import all declarations into it and export them from that module. Then in the project you can use this custom module in each module you want to use.

What about the bundle size, tree shaking will just throw away those declarations that are not used by that module.

```
NgModule({
   imports: [...here goes material modules],
   exports: [...here goes material modules]
})
export class CustomMaterialModule

...

NgModule({
   imports: [CustomMaterialModule]
})
export class YourModule {  }
```

Comment: how about browserAnimationModule, can I import it in app, layout and login?
I just try it, if I import all the angular material in layout or login module , the mat-slider is unable to drag.

Comment: `browserAnimationModule` you can add only in the `AppModule`

Comment: Is possible to make sure the browerAnimationModule load first before the angular material load? I had done the test just now. If I import angular material before browerAnimationModule, the slider is unable to drag.

Comment: You need to import BrowserAnimationModule first

Comment: ok.I will try it. Thank you so much for your answer. Its help me alot

Answer (score 6):

Create an array of the imported modules

```js
const matModules = [CdkTableModule,MatAutocompleteModule,MatButtonModule]; //etc.
```

Use it in your decorator in `imports` and  `exports` and create a new module

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [...matModules],
  exports: [...matModules]
})
export class MaterialConfigurationModule {}
```

Now you can simply import this module into your other modules.

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [MaterialConfigurationModule],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: how about browserAnimationModule, can I import it in app, layout and login?
I just try it, if I import all the angular material in layout or login module , the mat-slider is unable to drag.

Comment: I don't recall having imported it in my own project. Only in App module. You probably did something else.